# How to know if your SD card is SDHC/SDXC or SDSD in software?

Tags: sd

When initializing an SD card, I reach the point where I need to use the ACMD41 command. This command takes 4 bytes as argument, of which bit 30 is HCS. Which is set for SDHC and SDXC. If the SD card is neither, it should be set to 0. However I am at a loss as to how I know if this bit should be set.

I can use CMD58, which should return CCS as bit 30, which would indicate whether the card is SDHC or SDXC, but there does not seem to be a guarantee that this returns a correct value unless the card has been initialized with the ACMD41 command.

How can I set the HCS bit correctly in the initializing ACMD41 command without having a way to figure out what it should be set as? Or am I reading the specs wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.

As usual, I have read over a small detail. HCS of course means that the host supports SDHC and SDXC. It has nothing to do with the card.
As long as my code supports them, I can set the bit.